# Conditional expectation of X given X and Y

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value, measurable-functions

$X$ and $Y$ are just random variables and we know $X|Y$ follows some distribution.

I am trying to show that $\text{E}[X|X,Y]=X$.

I know a bit from measure theory that if X is $\sigma(X,Y)$-measurable then we are done. So I know X is $\sigma(X)$-measurable, and $\sigma(X)\subset \sigma(X,Y)$. Is this enough to show the result?

Also are their distributions the same: i.e. $X|X,Y=X$?

Thanks.

Comment: _Is this enough to show the result?_ 

Yes it is…

Comment: Thank you for verifying